# How to set backgroundColor of UIView to an image

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set background image of a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167623/how-to-set-background-image-of-a-view)

How to set UIView backgroundColor to an UIimage

```
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

i need to set to UIImage.

Comment: duplication! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167623/how-to-set-background-image-of-a-view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```