# How to set an image as background directly on a view without using imageview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, xcode-storyboard

```
 UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.jpg"]];
    _mainView.backgroundColor = background;
```

When i run this code, i am getting image as background on the view but like several patterns. I want to set image  to my view without using ImageView.
Is it possible to do via stroyboard?

Comment: Why would you want to do such thing? UIImageView is the simplest and most straightforward way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set background image of a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167623/how-to-set-background-image-of-a-view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use CaLayer object, assign your image as content of view's layer.
other items can be added as view's subviews as before.

```
class CustomViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // assign image as content of view's layer
        view.layer.contents = UIImage(named: "yourImageName")!.cgImage
    }   
}
```

for more info:

[Apple's CALayer doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer)

[CALayer tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2502/calayers-tutorial-for-ios-introduction-to-calayers-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

> When i run this code, i am getting image as background on the view but
>   like several patterns.

Because you are created a pattern and set it to the `UIView`. Method `initWithPatternImage` which *Initializes and returns a color object using the specified Quartz color reference.*

Better you could use `UIImageView` & add it to `UIView`